# How to rename multiple files by year to year basis in bash

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have multiple files named as

```
DOWN_1981_1.31.nc
DOWN_1982_1.31.nc
...
DOWN_2010_1.31.nc
```

I want to rename them to

```
DOWN_2040_1.31.nc
DOWN_2040_1.31.nc
DOWN_2041_1.31.nc
...
DOWN_2069_1.31.nc
```

How to do so using preferably a one-liner bash script?

The time set of the first bunch of files is from 1981 - 2010, which I want to rename from 2040 - 2069. The time blocks are 30 in both cases.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some more information. You mentioned recursion in the title but not in the question. And you didn't tell us _how_ the files should be renamed - do you want to add a fixed number of years to each filename? The difference between the first filenames in your example is 58 years, between the last filenames it's 55, so I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update after OP's comment**

After the OP's comment that not all files have the format `DOWN_1981_1.31.nc`, but there are also files formatted as `G_DOM_WC_m3_1981.nc` the `awk` solution I gave before doesn't seem to fit for the job.

The following script that uses `sed` is a bit more complex but seems to work fine (first `cd` into the directory containing the files):

```
for file in *;do mv $file $(echo $file | sed -r 's/(.*)([0-9]{4})(.*)/echo "\1$(echo "\2 + 59" | bc)\3"/e');done
```

This script uses regex to capture and change only the year, that has exactly 4 digits (`([0-9]{4})`), in the filename of all files in a directory, leaving the rest of the filename as is.

---

**Old solution**

The following simple script can do this for you (first `cd` into the directory containing the files):

```
for file in *;do mv $file $(echo $file | awk -F "_" '/DOWN/{print $1"_"$2 + 59"_"$3}');done
```

Comment: I am struggling to convert yet, since some of my files also start with G_DOM_WC_m3_1981.nc , G_DOM_WC_m3_1982.nc and so on...That implies its not restricted to a single word DOWN, some times the prefix is  G_DOM_WC_m3_ and G_IRRIG_CONS_USE_m3_1981.nc as well.

Comment: How should I proceed in those cases?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user962808 No problem!